# MySQL: Joining 3 tables, LIMIT results by first table?

Tags: mysql, join

I am selecting everything from prod_drop and joining 2 other tables for additional data. I do not want any of the rows from prod_drop to be repeated, I just want 1 row for each prod_drop row.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    prod_drop.*
    , prod_drop_products.product_id
    , cart_product.product_image_sm 
FROM 
    prod_drop   
LEFT JOIN 
    prod_drop_products 
ON 
    prod_drop.prod_drop_id = prod_drop_products.prod_drop_id 
LEFT JOIN 
    cart_product 
ON 
    prod_drop_products.product_id = cart_product.product_id 
ORDER BY 
    prod_drop_id 
DESC
```

These are the results:

```
prod_drop_id    prod_drop_name  prod_drop_available product_id  product_image_sm
51  Carat Weight    yes 4971    S5-3515Y_S.jpg
51  Carat Weight    yes 4970    S5-3515Y_S.jpg
51  Carat Weight    yes 4969    S5-3515Y_S.jpg
50  Carat Weight    yes 4959    S5-3515_S.jpg
50  Carat Weight    yes 4960    S5-3515_S.jpg
50  Carat Weight    yes 4958    S5-3515_S.jpg
49  Metal Quality   yes 3269    Q-8785X-14_S.jpg
49  Metal Quality   yes 3270    Q-8785X-14_S.jpg
48  Gold Color  yes 1635    1390-Y_S.jpg
48  Gold Color  yes 1390    PE0048-12W_S.jpg
```

But I only want one row per **prod_drop_id** (doesn't matter which) so essentially I want my results to be like this:

```
prod_drop_id    prod_drop_name  prod_drop_available product_id  product_image_sm
51  Carat Weight    yes 4971    S5-3515Y_S.jpg
50  Carat Weight    yes 4959    S5-3515_S.jpg
49  Metal Quality   yes 3269    Q-8785X-14_S.jpg
48  Gold Color  yes 1635    1390-Y_S.jpg
```

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: The reason I am trying to do this, is I am displaying a list of the prod-drops but each one can have several products associated with it, I am just trying to snag a single image of one of the associated products to show as a preview in the list. But as is, my list will repeat each prod-drop for as many times as there are products associated with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from your data, there are clearly more than one record in prod_drop_products for each record in prod_drop.  So if you only want one row in the output for each distinct row in prod_drop, then you need to either eliminate the output columns from this table, or decide which of the multiple rows in prod_drop_products you want the output to get it's value from for the query output columns that are coming from this table ( product_id, specifically) If it doesn't matter which product_id you output (this doesn;t make sense from a business perspective, but hey...) then you can use Min, or max() whichever you prefer.  If it does matter, then please specify what logic you want to use t omake that decision and the query can be edited t oreflect that...

Assuming Min() is ok, you can:

```
SELECT pd.prod_drop_id, pd.prod_drop_name, pd.prod_drop_available,     
  Min(pp.product_id), Min(cp.product_image_sm)
FROM prod_drop pd 
   LEFT JOIN prod_drop_products pp 
       ON pp.prod_drop_id = pd.prod_drop_id 
   LEFT JOIN cart_product cp
       ON cp.product_id = pp.product_id 
Group By pd.prod_drop_id, pd.prod_drop_name, pd.prod_drop_available
ORDER BY prod_drop_id DESC
```

Comment: Yes this works, thanks. I know it doesn't sound like it makes since from a business perspective but this is for internal use and I just need to show a thumbnail of a single associated product, it doesn't matter which because they are all essentially the same product just with different attributes, like blue stones vs red stones.

Comment: @John Then, do your really need the joins? Couldn't you simply do  
"SELECT pd.prod_drop_id, pd.prod_drop_name, pd.prod_drop_available
FROM prod_drop pd ORDER BY prod_drop_id DESC"? Do you really need to show the sample product_id and product_image_sm?

Answer (score 1):

I guess I would try a MAX (or MIN) on the two other tables.

Comment: +1 for being the first to post using MAX or MIN....but I marked Charles Bretana as the accepted answer because I wasn't sure how to implement it until I read his post.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for your cordiality. Please see my last comment on Charles's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.*, b.product_id, c.product_image_sm 
FROM prod_drop a
LEFT JOIN prod_drop_products b ON (a.prod_drop_id = b.prod_drop_id)
LEFT JOIN cart_product c ON (b.product_id = c.product_id)
GROUP BY a.prod_drop_id
ORDER BY a.prod_drop_id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your duplicates are only in the `cart_product` table, try this:

```
SELECT pd.*, pdp.product_id, cp.product_image_sm 
FROM prod_drop pd
LEFT JOIN prod_drop_products pdp ON pd.prod_drop_id = pdp.prod_drop_id 
LEFT JOIN (
    select product_id, min(product_image_sm) as product_image_sm
    from cart_product
    group by product_id
) cp ON pdp.product_id = cp.product_id 
ORDER BY pd.prod_drop_id DESC
```

If there are possible duplicates in both tables, you'll need something like:

```
SELECT pd.*, pdp.product_id, cp.product_image_sm 
FROM prod_drop pd
LEFT JOIN (
    select prod_drop_id, min(product_id) as product_id
    from prod_drop_products
    group by prod_drop_id   
) pdp ON pd.prod_drop_id = pdp.prod_drop_id 
LEFT JOIN (
    select product_id, min(product_image_sm) as product_image_sm
    from cart_product
    group by product_id
) cp ON pdp.product_id = cp.product_id 
ORDER BY pd.prod_drop_id DESC
```